# How do I find the Go module source cache?

Tags: go, circleci, go-modules

I've upgraded a project to Go 1.11 and enabled module support for my project, but it seems that CircleCI is re-downloading the dependencies on every build. I know CircleCI allows caching between rebuilds, so I've looked at the documentation for Go modules, and while it mentions a cache, I can't seem to find where it actually exists.

Where is the source cache for Go modules?

Comment: Are you using CircleCI 2.0? I'd assume so, since 1.0 is at end of life on August 31.

Comment: Yeah, CircleCI 2.0

Answer (score 42, accepted):

As of the final 1.11 release, the go *module cache* (used for storing downloaded modules and source code), is in the `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` location (see the docs [here](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules)). For clarification, the go *build cache* (used for storing recent compilation results) is in a different location.

[This article](https://dave.cheney.net/2018/07/14/taking-go-modules-for-a-spin), indicated that it's in the `$GOPATH/src/mod`, but in the timespan of the recent ~40 days, the golang team must have changed that target location. [This message thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-dev/RjSj4bGSmsw/KMHhU8fmAwAJ) has some discussion on why the downloaded items ended up in `$GOPATH/pkg`.

You can also use the `go mod download -json` command to see the downloaded modules/source metadata and their location on your local disk. Example output below:

```
$ go mod download -json
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.14.5
go: finding github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go v1.2.0
{
    "Path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go",
    "Version": "v1.2.0",
    "Info": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/@v/v1.2.0.info",
    "GoMod": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/@v/v1.2.0.mod",
    "Zip": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/@v/v1.2.0.zip",
    "Dir": "/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.2.0",
    "Sum": "h1:2f0pbAKMNNhvOkjI9BCrwoeIiduSTlYpD0iKEN1neuQ=",
    "GoModSum": "h1:zUsUQhAUjYzR8AuduJPCfhBuKWUaDbQiPOG+ouzmE1A="
}
{
    "Path": "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go",
    "Version": "v1.14.5",
    "Info": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/@v/v1.14.5.info",
    "GoMod": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/@v/v1.14.5.mod",
    "Zip": "/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/@v/v1.14.5.zip",
    "Dir": "/go/pkg/mod/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go@v1.14.5",
    "Sum": "h1:+l1m6QH6LypE2kL0p/G0Oh7ceCv+IVQ1h5UEBt2xjjU=",
    "GoModSum": "h1:ZRmQr0FajVIyZ4ZzBYKG5P3ZqPz9IHG41ZoMu1ADI3k="
}
```

That output is from a build on CircleCI 2.0, using their official `circleci/golang:1.11` image. This is a contrived example to show how you would include the `restore_cache` and `save_cache` steps for the new golang module cache location:

```
steps:
    - checkout
    - restore_cache:
       keys:
         - gomod-cache-{{ checksum "go.sum" }}
    - run: go vet ./...
    - save_cache:
        key: gomod-cache-{{ checksum "go.sum" }}
        paths:
          - /go/pkg/mod
```

Comment: thank you! this command revealed that all the downloaded modules are kept in the location `go/pkg/mod/cache` under my `$HOME`